# How do you do you get a value that was randomly chosen from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

This is currently my code.

```
if Pokémon == 'Charmander':
    selectyourmove = input('Select your move: Flamethrower, Fire Fang, 
Scratch or Ember: ')#select your move
    if selectyourmove == 'Flamethrower':
        numberchoosing1 = random.randint(20, 22)#randomly decides 
damage of the chosen move in the range
        print(choice, 'has lost' ,numberchoosing1, 'health out of its' 
,HP, 'health!')
```

My dictionary is quite simple. It is:

```
HP = {'Char':'60', 'Squir':'50', 'Pika':'80', 'Eve':'50', 'Bulb':'70', 'Clef':'100'}
```

Also all these have been defined.

How do I get a value that was randomly chosen from a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st way is to use [`dict.popitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem):

> Remove and return an arbitrary (key, value) pair from the dictionary.
>   `popitem()` is useful to destructively iterate over a dictionary, as often used in set algorithms. If the dictionary is empty, calling `popitem()` raises a `KeyError`.

Note, that this method randomness actually comes from implementation of hashing algorithm and python `dict` elements layout. That's more obscurity than randomness.

The 2nd way, the truely 'random', is using the [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choice). It doesn't modify the dict, as chooses random index in the list supplied to it:

```
import random
hp = {'Char':'60', 'Squir':'50', 'Pika':'80', 'Eve':'50', 'Bulb':'70', 'Clef':'100'}
print(random.choice(list(hp.keys())))
```

Illustration of working principle:

```
>>> random.choice(list(HP.keys()))
'Pika'
>>> random.choice(list(HP.keys()))
'Clef'
>>> random.choice(list(HP.keys()))
'Pika'
```

The list is constructed here from `.keys()`, but when you need pairs (like from `popitem()`) you could use `.items()`:

```
>>> random.choice(list(HP.items()))
('Clef', '100')
>>> random.choice(list(HP.items()))
('Pika', '80')
>>> random.choice(list(HP.items()))
('Char', '60')
```

The same way, of course the `.values()` will work producing only right-hand elements of `dict` items though, thus won't give you much satisfaction unlike `.keys()` or `.items()` does.

PS: Then if you need the reproduce prev. run, you can fix the 'randomness' with [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.seed)

Comment: Also, how do you make it print its health? Because right now, it prints the dictionary, not the health of the pokemon

Comment: Just a sec, I'll add this to the answer

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by "value". A dictionary is a set of `key,value` pairs, so technically the *values* of your dictionary are just the strings `'50', '60', '50', '100', '70', '80'`, and the *keys* are the strings `'Eve', 'Char', 'Squir', 'Clef', 'Bulb', 'Pika'`.

You can these collections by using `HP.keys()` and `HP.values()`, and you can use `list()` to cast these collections to lists. Then, you can use `random.choice` to get a random value.

So to get a random key from your dictionary (which it seems like is what you actually want), you could do:

```
import random
keys = HP.keys()
key_list = list(keys)
choice = random.choice(key_list)
```

Or, more concisely:

```
import random
choice = random.choice(list(HP.keys()))
```

Then you can get the associated value for that key with `HP[choice]`